# Generate random and uniques ids in django

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

How can I generate identifiable ids usable as primary keys for my Django application?

For example, suppose I have two tables storing information about bikes and cars. I would like the keys for the bike table to look like `'bike1235efghffgtuf'` and the keys for the car table to look like `'car24343fhhgiy6ury'`. That is, they should have enough random text to avoid collisions, but it should also be easy to see which table they belong to.

I know that Django automatically adds ids if we don't provide primary keys, but they are simple numbers that don't indicate which table they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily generate such keys using the `random` module. To make them table specific, simply prepend a table unique identifier to a randomly generated key:

```
import random, string
KEYLEN = 15
prefix = "car"
key = prefix + "".join(random.choice(string.letters+string.digits) for _ in range(KEYLEN))
```

Here are some samples this gives:

```
'caraeCqCA2LvMf9oLn'
'car7vAHCzaeuT7uAgN'
'carQ6bkckGfmdxMGim'
'car9WlxbcV1uOhXQkj'
'carONwavdLrMdc804g'
'carSwBU0WkNgT7YL1l'
'carCtWClbz9khoMDmU'
```

If your keys are very sufficiently long and random, it becomes very unlikely to have repeats.  However, if you are worried about this, simply store the keys to a list.  Then each time you generate a new just check the list:

```
while True:
    key = prefix + "".join(random.choice(string.letters+string.digits) for _ in range(KEYLEN))
    if not key in key_list:
        key_list.append(key)
        break
```